# How would I go with refactoring my controller's custom methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a StackOverflow-like clone for studying purposes. Users have this ability to vote for someone's question, bringing its score up or down. My method works fine, however the repetition and the amount of controller logic are bothering me.

- User has_many Votes
- Question has_many Votes
- Votes belong to Question/User

routes:

```
concern :voteable do
  post 'votes/voteup',   to: 'votings#voteup',   as: :voteup
  post 'votes/votedown', to: 'votings#votedown', as: :votedown
end

resources :questions, concerns: [:commentable, :favoriteable, :voteable] do
  ...
end
```

votes controller

```
class VotingsController < ApplicationController
  def voteup
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])

    unless @question.user == current_user # checks if the user is the author
      if current_user.voted?(@question.id) #checks if user already voted
        @vote = current_user.votes.find_by(question_id: @question)
        @vote.update_attributes(score: 1)
      else
        @vote = Vote.create(user: current_user, question: @question, score: 1)
      end
    end

    redirect_to :back
  end

  def votedown
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])

    unless @question.user == current_user
      if current_user.voted?(@question.id) 
        @vote = current_user.votes.find_by(question_id: @question)
        @vote.update_attributes(score: -1)
      else
        @vote = Vote.create(user: current_user, question: @question, score: -1)
      end
    end

    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

**voted?** is a method I've extracted to my User model

```
  def voted?(question)
    true if self.votes.where(question_id: question) 
  end
```

I would like to get rid of repetition in these two methods, but how?
Should I create one method like VOTE and one route leading to it with specified params (up/down) and then assign the score based on if/else? Sounds dirty to me, but that is the only thing that comes into my mind. I'm sure there has to be a beautiful Rails-way solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The User class could hold a method called `vote_for(question, score)` and defined like this:

```
# class User
def vote_for(question, score)
  vote = self.votes.where(question_id: question.id).first || Vote.new(user: self, question: question)
  vote.score = score
  vote.save
end


class VotingsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_question, only: %w(voteup votedown)

  def voteup
    current_user.vote_for(@question, 1)
  end

  def votedown
    current_user.vote_for(@question, -1)
  end

  protected
  def set_question
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end
```

---

A little tip: You should refactor your `.voted?` method of the User class to this:

```
def voted?(question)
  self.votes.exists?(question_id: question)
end
```

This will either return `TRUE` or `FALSE`, not a complete object retrieved from the DB and then translated into a Ruby object.

Comment: thank you. I went your way and with some refactoring afterwards my code looks much nicer now